# How do I change the Envelope From in Postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix, wordpress, amazon-ses

Linux server that uses Postfix to send mail via Amazon SES.  When sending email from Wordpress, the emails are rejected due to an improper Envelope From address.

**How can I configure Postfix to always use myemail@mydomain.com as the Envelope From address?**

I am looking for a default property I can configure and not a code based solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put the following in `/etc/postfix/canonical`:

```
# Use the empty regexp to map *any* address to the desired envelope sender.
// my-fixed-envelope-sender@example.org
```

Append the following to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/canonical
canonical_classes = envelope_sender
```

Reload Postfix:

```
postfix reload
```

Note that this only rewrites the envelope sender (as asked), not the "From:" header. Also, if you set this on a host that *receives* mail from the outside world, havoc will likely ensue.

See [canonical(5)](http://www.postfix.org/canonical.5.html) and the documentation for the [canonical_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#canonical_maps) and [canonical_classes](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#canonical_classes) options for more information.

Comment: Don't use `//` as that also matches the null sender e.g. for delivery errors. Use `/./`

Answer (score 5):

You can also set the envelope-sender from php.

Put this in your apache vhost config if you are using mod_php:

```
php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fyou@example.com"
```

Or set the value in the php.ini file (which could be server wide or per user depending on your system):

```
sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fyou@example.com"
```

this only works if the sending script uses the php mail() function.

Comment: It is also possible to use `-F` option to set name before mail: `-F abc` -> **abc** <you@example.com>

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the masquerade_domains setting which will go in main.cf. I am not sure what you mean by

> I am looking for a default property I can configure and not a code based solution.

Please take a look at the following link:

[Postfix Configuration Parameters - masquerade_domains](http://www.postfix.com/postconf.5.html#masquerade_domains)

Answer (score -1):

Both questions have good answers:
[Change Envelope From to match From header in Postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/369174/change-envelope-from-to-match-from-header-in-postfix) and 
[how to have all postfix emails have ONE from email address](https://serverfault.com/questions/319819/how-to-have-all-postfix-emails-have-one-from-email-address)

You probably want `sender_canonical_maps=myemail@mydomain.com`