# Postfix not receiving bounce mails

Tags: nginx, php, postfix, gmail, email-bounces

I am using Postfix to only send Mails out (via my noreply mail), which works great.

I would like to use my support mail, which is running on the server of my mail provider, to receive user replies and bounce mails from e.g. Gmail.

With Reply-To: support@xxxxxx.com in the Mailing Header users are already able to send a mail directly to my support mail. I even have created a forward for noreply@xxxxx.com -> support@xxxxx.com on my mail provider.

In ****etc/postfix/main.cf**** I've already entered below code & did **service reload postfix**

```
bounce_notice_recipient = support@xxxxxxx.com
```

However, I am still not receiving any bounce mail from GMail etc. On my "normal user" mail accounts I always receive a bounce for the mail address I am using for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Bounces (aka delivery status messages) are generally sent to the envelope sender address of the affected mail.
This address is set to the sender address of the mail itself by default.
In order to redirect bounces to a different address you have to set the envelope sender address explicitly. A good answer on how to do that in Postfix can be found at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/533912/how-do-i-change-the-envelope-from-in-postfix).

The `bounce_notice_recipient` option does something quite different.
It sets the recipient for bounce *notices*, ie. notifications about bounces which originate on your own server.